# Flutter firebase display collectiongroup items in a Listview

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use a collectiongroup query to fetch items from firestore however no data is returned. I'm sure the data is there because I have a print statement that prints out some of this data.

This is how my code is structured

```
     getSpotinfo() async {
               //get data from userSpots collectionGroup
    
            await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup("userSpots").get();
          }
    
    FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
//This is always returning the circular progress indicator
                            future: getSpotinfo(),
                            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                return ListView.builder(
                                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                    itemCount: totalSlots > 4 ? 4 : totalSlots,
                                    itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                                      return Text(
                                          snapshot.data[i]["spaceName"]);
                                    });
                              } else {
                                return CircularProgressIndicator();
                              }
                            },
                          )
```